# Is the value of RAND_MAX always (2^n)-1?

Tags: c++, random

I'm interested for C++, though I suspect that simply imports the C standard definition. I believe the answer is no for what the standard says, but I'm most interested in the in-practice answer.

If RAND_MAX is always (2^n)-1 (where n is some natural number - in effect the number of random binary digits in a random number), that simplifies dealing with an issue that turned up recently moving code from MinGW GCC to Linux GCC. RAND_MAX seems to be bigger (I didn't check, but possibly equal to INT_MAX or whatever the symbol is), so some old naively written RAND_MAX-isn't-big-enough-so-work-around-it code backfired. Now I need to decide just how general I need this library to be, considering the fiddliness of writing code that copes correctly with the possibility of overflow without making assumptions about e.g. the width of an int.

Anyway, are there any reasonably widely used C++ compilers that use something other than (2^n)-1 for RAND_MAX?

Also, am I correct that ((RAND_MAX | (RAND_MAX >> 1)) == RAND_MAX) is always and only true if RAND_MAX is equal to ((2^n)-1) for some unsigned integer n. I believe RAND_MAX is technically an int, but it makes no sense to have a negative or fractional value, so I think I can safely discount those. Bit-fiddling doesn't normally bother me, but I keep thinking the expression looks wrong, and I can't figure out why.

Finally, although I'm not going to be happy until I've got a working solution of my own, what *should* I be using for random numbers rather than write it myself? I need random numbers in the range 0 <= x < parameter, and I especially want as-equal-as-sanely-possible probabilities for all numbers. For example, taking (rand() % upperbound) gives a bias towards smaller values, especially when the upperbound is large - I want to avoid that.

Is there a Boost or C++0x thing for that?

**EDIT**

Following something in the "Related" bit on the side of the page shows there is indeed a way to get random numbers with given lower and upper bounds in boost.

Comment: For those of us interested in this question could you clarify/edit the meaning of the variable n in 2^n - 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what the guarantees on `RAND_MAX` are, but you'd better avoid it if possible because of the number of broken implementations around and because it starts cycling quite quickly in today's applications. Getting a uniform distribution is described [here](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html).

I recommend [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_random.html) instead. The [Mersenne twister](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost/mt19937.html) generator represents a good tradeoff between speed, memory use and quality.

Comment: I already have a Mersenne twister implementation - no good reason, just it was covered in a book. A good library version would be more practical, of course. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: I'd switch to Boost if I were you; it cleanly separates PRNG from probability distributions and includes a `random_device` class for proper seeding (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/random_device.html).

Comment: Accepted about 80% because of the Misconceptions about rand link - the Boost point is more practical, but that link is very interesting.

Comment: BTW - well anticipated with the random_device point. One reason I never actually used my MT other than to play was the "OK, so how do I seed this properly" issue. I figured if I wasn't doing that right, there wasn't much point changing anything.

Comment: I think Mersenne twister is a bit old now I would use the SMFT: http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/SFMT/index.html

Comment: the [`<random>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) has been available since C++11. No reason to use boost for this

Answer (score 6):

- I don't know any implementation for which RAND_MAX is not one less than a power of two, but that isn't mandated by the standard;
- ((RAND_MAX | (RAND_MAX >> 1)) == RAND_MAX) is indeed a way to test if RAND_MAX is one less than a power of two.
- I'm using

  ```
  int alea(int n){ 
    assert (0 < n && n <= RAND_MAX); 
    int partSize = 
      n == RAND_MAX ? 1 : 1 + (RAND_MAX-n)/(n+1); 
    int maxUsefull = partSize * n + (partSize-1); 
    int draw; 
    do { 
      draw = rand(); 
    } while (draw > maxUsefull); 
    return draw/partSize; 
  }
  ```

to make as evenly distributed as possible random numbers from rand().

Comment: I can't quite use that function, because the RAND_MAX is too small issue still exists on Windows. That said, I could just conditionally compile to choose between that and the use-two-randoms-to-make-one version (the existing code does that combined with something very similar to your code). That's what I did to shut the error up for the moment anyway - it just seems like cheating is all.

Answer (score 4):

For implementations of `rand` which use a (variant of a) Linear Congruential Generator (most of them), then RAND_MAX will be a prime number, not necessarily of the form 2<sup>n</sup> - 1 (a "Mersenne prime").

Also, 2<sup>31</sup>-1 is a prime number, but if n is not prime, 2<sup>n</sup> - 1 is not prime.

(Indeed, if n = ab, then 2<sup>n</sup> - 1 = (2<sup>a</sup> - 1)(1 + 2<sup>b</sup> + 2<sup>2b</sup> + ...) )

Around 2<sup>64</sup>, the only Mersenne prime is 2<sup>61</sup> - 1.

And you should really avoid linear congruential generators if you have any half serious requirement about random number generation. Actually, I'd say that except for a tetris game, you should avoid `rand()` from the C library.

Comment: Interesting. OTOH - "tetris" isn't really so far from the mark - and for a lot of people, not just me. The number of people developing security-critical crypto libraries, or other apps where you really care how random that generator really is, is probably quite small compared with e.g. the number of people who want to supplement their regression tests with some randomish-test-data based tests or the number of people writing simple games.

Comment: @Steve314: Linear cong. generators have serious flaws which makes them unable even for the simplest mathematical applications. See eg. http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/lcg_planes.shtml to see what I mean.

Comment: the key words being "mathematical applications", and I can accept that even for some very simple ones you may need a stronger generator. I'll add "engineering simulation", which also probably comes under my "other apps where you really care" blanket. But seriously - for many programmers, random numbers are something we rarely need, and when we do `rand` is almost always good enough. Sometimes, even "add one to the last number" is enough for generating some arbitrary data, saving the minor hassles of seeding and looking up the right header to include.

Comment: @Alexande - that said, the world will probably be a better place when more people start using the C++0x standard library random number support. The stronger (default?) random number generator is more of an added bonus, though, given the support for various distributions and probably other goodies.

Answer (score 4):

According to both ISO C (C99 to C17 at least) and POSIX (Issue 7, 2016 Edition), `RAND_MAX` shall be at least 32767, i.e. 2<sup>15</sup>−1, and there are no other restrictions.

Under GNU/Linux, `RAND_MAX` is guaranteed to be exactly 2147483647 = 2<sup>31</sup>−1 on all architectures for consistency with POSIX concerning the `random()` function: [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/random.html) specifies that the return value is in the range from 0 to 2<sup>31</sup>−1, and the Linux [random(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/random) man page documents the range as being from 0 to `RAND_MAX`.

Comment: The original question is pretty irrelevant now - it was asked in 2011 and focussed on C++, but C++ gained new libraries for random numbers in the 2011 standard (based on the Boost random library IIRC). Of course C++ still imports most of the C standard, and this is the relevant information from C. And `rand` is still included with that, though it's use is strongly discouraged - e.g. `std::random_shuffle` (which used `rand` behind the scenes) was deprecated in C++14 and replaced with `std::shuffle` (which has an extra argument for a "uniform random generator").

Comment: @Steve314 However, the question is still relevant for C if one does not want to use an external library.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `RAND_MAX <= INT_MAX` is not a restriction, just a consequence that the `rand` function returns an `int`.

Comment: OK, fair enough,

Answer (score 3):

In Embacadero C++ Builder, there are two variables defined in stdlib.h:

```
/* Maximum value returned by "rand" function*/
#define RAND_MAX  0x7FFFU

/* Maximum value returned by "_lrand" function (also used by random() macro)*/
#define LRAND_MAX 0x7FFFFFFFU
```

Comment: Showing the value from a specific compiler doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 2):

In the standard GNU header file, stdlib.h, there is a definition of RAND_MAX which should be the sole definition in your system:

```
#define RAND_MAX    2147483647
```

The value 2147483647 = 0x7fffffff is the largest <strike>un</strike>signed 32-bit integer.

The rand functions, defined in stdlib.h, are reliable in standard GNU environments with one caveat: multi-threading (pthread) environments will need pthread code to synchronize in order to protect the rand(), srand(), and rand_r() calls since they are not reentrant.  See the [man page for srand](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html) for an explanation.

RAND_MAX should not be defined anywhere else in your system.  If you are seeing a different value for RAND_MAX or seeing a definition of RAND_MAX somewhere besides stdlib.h, then this must be a non-standard, non-portable environment.  Windows is notorious for making standardization and portability difficult (E.g. sockets implementation and APIs).

Answer (score 1):

In GCC (4.6) RAND_MAX = 0x7FFFFFFF (31bit)
In MS Visual Studio (2012) RAND_MAX = 0x7FFF (15bit)

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. It shows 2 examples but does this really hold for all compilers? Is it guaranteed by the standard?